# Not able to run macro when specific Worksheet is active

Tags: excel, vba

I have macro for copying data from one sheet `GanttChart` to another `TableForOL`. When `TableForOL` is active below macro can't be run:

```
Sub safdsfdsffds()

    copyToTable "Spare parts", "Spare parts end", "18", "GanttChart"

End Sub
```

I know that name is quite offensive but there must be some other reason for current problem.

Here is `copyToTable` sub routine:

```
Private Sub copyToTable(SearchWordOne As String, SearchWordTwo As String, RowToPaste As String, OperatingWorksheet As String)

    Dim FirstWord, SecondWord
            
    Set FirstWord = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(OperatingWorksheet).Range("C:C").Find(SearchWordOne, LookIn:=xlValues)
    Set SecondWord = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(OperatingWorksheet).Range("C:C").Find(SearchWordTwo, LookIn:=xlValues)

    ' Copy - Paste name
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(OperatingWorksheet)
        .Range(Cells(FirstWord.Row + 1, FirstWord.Column), Cells(SecondWord.Row - 1, FirstWord.Column)).Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TableForOL").Range("B" & RowToPaste).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End With
    
    ' Copy - Paste amount
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(OperatingWorksheet)
        .Range(Cells(FirstWord.Row + 1, FirstWord.Column + 10), Cells(SecondWord.Row - 1, FirstWord.Column + 10)).Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TableForOL").Range("C" & RowToPaste).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End With

    ' Copy - Paste price
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(OperatingWorksheet)
        .Range(Cells(FirstWord.Row + 1, FirstWord.Column + 17), Cells(SecondWord.Row - 1, FirstWord.Column + 17)).Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TableForOL").Range("E" & RowToPaste).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End With

End Sub
```

Error message after running `safdsfdsffds` when Worksheet `TableForOL` is active:

[image]

pointing at first:

```
.Range(Cells(FirstWord.Row + 1, FirstWord.Column), Cells(SecondWord.Row - 1, FirstWord.Column)).Copy
```

Comment: At first glance I'd say you need to add a `.` lbefore `Cells` like that `.Range(.Cells(FirstWord.Row + 1, FirstWord.Column), .Cells(SecondWord.Row - 1, FirstWord.Column)).Copy`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
.Range(Cells(FirstWord.Row + 1, FirstWord.Column + 10), Cells(SecondWord.Row - 1, FirstWord.Column + 10)).Copy
```

write exactly:

```
 .Range(.Cells(FirstWord.Row + 1, FirstWord.Column + 10), .Cells(SecondWord.Row - 1, FirstWord.Column + 10)).Copy
```

The dots before `Cells` make an important difference.

Without the dot before `Cells` the parent worksheet of the `Cells` is the `ActiveSheet` (or the worksheet in which the code is present, if it is not in a module/class). And the parent of the `.Range` is the one, given in the `With` Statement. Thus, having two different parents is causing 1004.

*This is probably the most common error in [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) that literally **everyone** hits, once they start programming here (So you can be proud of yourself, achievement unlocked).*